Render deploying fail
About my backend project:

NODE.js && Express
Database use "MySQL", && ORM sequelize
without docker

github link: link
This is my first time to deploy my project. And I chose "Render" for deploing.
However, after setting details and create new deploy. It always show fail and without any log below.
what should I do?
Setting Details


Fail Message:

env variable

.env example

package.json


I have tried change "build commend" and "start comment" into only "npm install" and  "node app.js", but still the same.
